# Server Database Setup file

Tags: c#, mysql

I've created a multiple user application in WinForm and it have a database on the server which is on the other computer. So far, i set up the server database (MySql) manually and create each tables in the database manually as well. I was wondering is there a way to create (maybe an exe file) to automate the entire process?

I've did some searching on the internet but most of the answer i get are the configuration of the database which i've go through it when i did the manual set up. I developed the application and the database separately so what is related to the database in my application are the connection string only. i did managed to publish the application and now i need to find a way to publish my server database.

Comment: Does each application uses its own MySQL account? anycase you may create a procedure which executes with security=definer (which is root) and creates the table by the information provided by the client.

Comment: So far, all the application use the same account to access the database but if there is better solution to improve the performance I'll consider changing it.
But I think you misunderstand my question. 
what i'm trying to solve is the Database setup process on the server. 
Which kind of like how we install a software.

Comment: *all the application use the same account to access the database* I doubt that this is good solution... of course I mean separate applications, not separate instances of the same application.

Comment: ohh yeahh, i mean all the instances of the same application are using the same account.
As there is only one application calling the database for now

Comment: If so then (1) I do not see the problem with tables creation - use described method (2) one table with additional column which allows to identify the instance-creator seems to be more useful, because DDL operations from the client (except initial DB creation or DB structure upgrade performed by special upgrading tool) are not good practice in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mysql you cannot automate the install of the mysql software, unless you have a paid for enterprise licence or you release your software as open source under GPL.

To automate mysql installation, you can use [mysql installer console](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/MySQLInstallerConsole.html).

What you can definitely automate is the deployment of your mysql data structure and the configuration of the mysql instance.

The former requires an sql script that creates the database and all other database objects (tables, indedes, views, users, etc) that you can execute as part of an install process. The latter requires overwriting or adding your settings to my.cnf / my.ini configuration files.